# Angular 2 form checkboxes in templates

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

So the problem here is the "getNumber" function, but i dont know why. When I pass the parameter directly like "[1,2,3]" then checkboxes works. But when I pass the function call they stop working. Why?

```
 <ng-template #list let-orgs>
        <div *ngFor="let num of orgs">
            <input type="checkbox" /> {{ num }}
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="list; context:{ $implicit: getNumbers() }"></ng-container>
```

the function is simple like:

```
public getNumbers(): number[] {
        return [1,2,3];
    }
```

Comment: Have you thought of creating a Plunker and linking it. I'll take a look for you if you do.

Comment: I finally found out whats causing the issue but I have no idea why... I updated the question and left only relevant code

Comment: Does it work when using a getter function like `public get numbers() { return [1,2,3] }`?

Comment: No it doesnt, just checked

Comment: Which version angular are you using? Because i just tested you setup with the latest version and it's working fine.

Comment: I have ~4.2.5 version and will be updating to 3.1 later today. for now i fixed it by preparing data in component and passing that data instead of function call. But I still dont get why it doesnt work with it